# How to get BaseUrl from Context.Request in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Given a request like the following:

```
 http://www.sitename.com/controller/action/2
```

I'm trying to extract `http://www.sitename.com` using one of the Context.Request.Url methods.  I've tried AbsoluteUrl and some others but haven't had any luck.  Is there any built-in method to achieve this or do I have to write my own utility function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, 
                                              UriFormat.SafeUnescaped)
```

This will give you the http or https as well as the domain from a given URL.  Depending on where you use this method, the HttpContext.Current may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL helper for that:

```
Url.Content("~")
```